# Linear regression model with a distribution over regression equations

Tags: inference, least-squares, linear-model, finite-mixture-model

Suppose that the observations $(y_t, x_t, k_t)_{t=1}^N$ satisfy the linear regression equation:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y_t = \begin{cases} 
x_t \beta + e_t & w.p. \; \theta \\
k_t \gamma + e_t & w.p. \; 1-\theta 
\end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
with $\mathbb{E}(e_t|x_t, k_t)=0$ and other usual assumptions.

Can I estimate $\beta*\theta$ and $\gamma*(1-\theta)$?

Comment: What does "w.p." mean??  Are the apparent error terms "$e_t$" the same quantities in both cases or not?

Comment: w.p. is standard notation for 'with probability,' it denotes a random variable. Not sure how the error term being the same is relevant, the error term is defined as the difference between $y_t$ and the conditional mean. Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for $\theta$ to be a random variable.  Would you mean that there is a lurking random Bernoulli$(\theta)$ variable *independent* of $e_t$ and that $y_t = kx_t\beta + e_t$ conditional on $U=1$ and otherwise $y_t = k_t\gamma + e_t$ when $U=0$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional mean of $y_t$ is $\mathbb{E}(y_t|x_t, k_t) = x_t \beta \theta + k_t \gamma (1-\theta)$, so parameters can be identified with the regression $$y_t = a_1 x_t + a_2 k_t + e_t$$